# Django URL pattern using pk error

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using the latest version of python3 and Django2, trying to do an URL pattern that is dynamic and changes for every different variable, Here are the codes:

**urls.py**

```
path('categories/<int:item_category>/', views.item_category, name="item_category"),
```

**views.py**

```
def item_category(request, pk):
    item_category = get_object_or_404(Categories, pk=pk)

    return render(request, 'items_modal.html', {'item_category': item_category})
```

**models.py**

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    category_name  = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

    def item_category(self):
        return reverse('item_category', args=[self.pk])
```

**home.html**

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"><h2 align="center"> محتويات المخزن</h2></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     {% for cat in all_cats %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a href="{% url 'item_category' item_category.pk %}"" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">{{ cat }}</a></th>

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

when I try to go to open the home page it gives me the error :

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'item_category' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['categories\\/(?P<item_category>[0-9]+)\\/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.0.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'item_category' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['categories\\/(?P<item_category>[0-9]+)\\/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 632
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\python\\Django\\nothing',
 'C:\\Users\\Dev3\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Dev3\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Dev3\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Dev3\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Dev3\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 24 Apr 2018 09:39:46 +0000
```

Comment: As an aside, it's recommended to use the singular for model names (e.g. `Category` instead of `Categories`. Also I would avoid using the same variable name for the view `item_category` and the category instance inside the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Reverse for 'item_category' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['categories\\/(?P<item_category>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

In the error message, `with arguments '('',)'` is telling you that the argument in the `url` tag evaluated to the empty string `''`.

Looking at your template, you loop through `{% for cat in all_cats %}` but then you use `item_category.pk` inside the loop. You probably want `cat.pk`:

```
{% for cat in all_cats %}
<tr>
  <th scope="row"><a href="{% url 'item_category' cat.pk %}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">{{ cat }}</a></th>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: and it worked like charm. Thank you @Alasdair 
Don't you know how to use that keyword in the output page as a variable, I want to use this cat.pk for the link the user clicked as a filter in the output page

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already use the `pk` in the `item_category` view: `item_category = get_object_or_404(Categories, pk=pk)`.

Comment: When the user clicks on a text(the `{{ cat }}` variable i used in HTML ) it take him to the URL  `/categories/(pk)/`  , i want to use the clicked `{{ cat }}` as <h1> title in the new opened page

Comment: In that view, you are using the context `{'item_category': item_category}`. Therefore you can use `{{ item_category }}` in the template for that view. If you're still stuck, please ask a new question because this is a separate issue.